# How to use typescript-language-server with monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I want to use this npm package as my lsp (https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server), but I don't know how to connect it to monaco-editor, can anyone help me?